# asp.net mvc web request says proxy error 502 only when deployed to iis

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, proxy

Hi i am creating some web requests through my controller in my asp.net MVC apps.To authenticate proxy i am using

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials =  System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

This works fine while making web request to external servers like 
   e.g: http://www.google.com or whatever

but when i make request to my localhost it says proxy error and gives a error code 502. What could be the possible cause of this error? Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Is this a network-level proxy or a local machine proxy?  Requests to `localhost` probably bypass the proxy altogether.

Comment: this is a network-level proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the issue with IIS which actually doesn't read the host file so have to manually assign the proxy server and the bypass list to the web.config file. Good resource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31465c77.aspx